# NSPredicate SELF CONTAINS[c] returns value contained in longer text first

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, sorting, nspredicate

I am using UISearchBar to sort UITableView. Each value in the array which the table is populated with, can have up to 3 words

@"Pineapple", @"Pineapple Green", @"Apple Green", @"Apple Green, Raw"...

I am using NSPredicate method below:

```
 NSArray *words = [text componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    NSMutableArray *predicateList = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSString *word in words) {
        if ([word length] > 0) {
            NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] %@", word];
            [predicateList addObject:pred];
        }
    }
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:predicateList];
    NSLog(@"%@", predicate);
```

It works, but it doesn't sort the values by the closest relative, but instead it takes always the first matching value from array by its index. That means, if I want to find "apple" and type it in the SearchBar, the result will be:

```
Pineapple
Pineapple Green
Apple
Apple Green
```

I can not use predicate BEGINSWITH, because if I search for "Green Apple", the result will be blank. In this particular case I could use to sort the result Ascending, but in another case such as TEA it won't work, because the string "TEA" is contained in other words such as STEAM and that would come first.

I am out of options here, is there a way to have logical result output according to the search? In case of looking for "Apple":

```
Apple    
Apple Green
```

//------- ADITION

Thanks for your replies guys. I was thinking about custom logic and came up with this. I am sure it is dirty code and can be improved, but it is performing much better now. It still doesn't display the result in organised way, but the search has all items related now, no matter in what order you typing the search:

```
NSArray *words = [text componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

    NSString *word1;
    NSString *word2;
    NSString *word3;
    NSPredicate *predicate;

    if (words.count == 1) {
        word1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [words objectAtIndex:0]];
        predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF CONTAINS[cd] %@ OR SELF LIKE[cd] %@", word1, word1];
    }
    else if (words.count == 2) {
        word1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [words objectAtIndex:0]];
        word2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [words objectAtIndex:1]];
        predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF CONTAINS[cd] %@ AND SELF CONTAINS[cd] %@", word1, word2];
    }
    else if (words.count == 3) {
        word1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [words objectAtIndex:0]];
        word2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [words objectAtIndex:1]];
        word3 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [words objectAtIndex:2]];
        predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF CONTAINS[cd] %@ AND SELF CONTAINS[cd] %@ AND SELF CONTAINS[cd] %@", word1, word2,word3];
    }
    NSArray *sortedArray = [self.allItemsArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    filteredTableData = [sortedArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

If someone knows how to sort the results to get closest match, please share it. Thank you

Comment: A predicate *filters* data, sorting is done with a *sort descriptor*. But I don't see how the desired order could be achieved with a sort descriptor in your case, so you probably need custom logic to build the result set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boom! I got it! All I had to add was NSSortDescriptor. Now it seems easy:

```
NSArray *words = [text componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

    NSString *word1;
    NSString *word2;
    NSString *word3;
    NSPredicate *predicate;

    if (words.count == 1) {
        word1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [words objectAtIndex:0]];
        predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF CONTAINS[cd] %@ OR SELF LIKE[cd] %@", word1, word1];

    }
    else if (words.count == 2) {
        word1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [words objectAtIndex:0]];
        word2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [words objectAtIndex:1]];
        predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF CONTAINS[cd] %@ AND SELF CONTAINS[cd] %@", word1, word2];

    }
    else if (words.count == 3) {
        word1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [words objectAtIndex:0]];
        word2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [words objectAtIndex:1]];
        word3 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [words objectAtIndex:2]];
        predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF CONTAINS[cd] %@ AND SELF CONTAINS[cd] %@ AND SELF CONTAINS[cd] %@", word1, word2,word3];

    }
    NSArray *sortedArray = [self.allItemsArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    NSSortDescriptor *lengthSorter = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"length" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:lengthSorter];
    filteredTableData = [sortedArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

It works the way I wanted now! But if you have any improvement suggestions, please share them!

Thank you

Comment: needs a solution where the number of word count varies. like if I need a solution for 5 words then it is difficult to have 5 if else block

Comment: @ManishNahar You can add a loop, I'll adjust the above answer in a new answer, to allow for the code formatting.

Answer (score 1):

One way of solving this would be to apply the predicate to an NSSet instead of an NSArray. Something like this:

```
     NSSet *tempSet = [NSSet setWithArray:words];
     tempSet = [tempSet filteredSetUsingPredicate:predicate];
     resultsArray = [tempSet allObjects];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: How would using a set (which has no defined order by design) help to get the results in the desired order?

Comment: Thanks, but this method shows only 1 item at all times, no other suggestions containing or matching the string are shown...

Answer (score 0):

A solution containing a loop, where the number of search words is irrelevant.

```
NSArray *words = [text componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
NSMutableArray *andPredicateSections = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:1];

for (NSString *nextWord in words) {
    NSPredicate *aPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF CONTAINS[cd] %@", nextWord];
    [andPredicateSections addObject:aPredicate];
}

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:andPredicateSections];
NSArray *sortedArray = [self.allItemsArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```